# Multiple Delete from table in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I want to delete multiple members form the group,
The if statement successfully assigns multiple members from a single group but the Deletion(ifelse) deletes only one member !

```
if( isset( $_POST['add_member'] ) )
    {
        $group_id = $_POST['group_id'];

        foreach ($_POST['member_id'] as $member) {

         $query="SELECT id FROM member_group
                    WHERE member_id = $member AND `group_id` =  $group_id[0]";
        if(!mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($connection,$query)))
        {
            $query="INSERT INTO `member_group`(member_id,group_id)                                                                       VALUES($member,$group_id[0])";
            mysqli_query($connection,$query) or die(mysqli_errno($connection));
        }
           echo "<div class='alert alert-info'>Member Assigned. </div>";
        }
    }
    elseif( isset( $_POST['remove_member'] ) )
    {
         $member_id = $_POST['member_id'];

         foreach ($_POST['group_id'] as $group) {
            $query="DELETE FROM member_group
                WHERE group_id = $group AND `member_id` =  $member_id[0]" ;
         $rows = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
```

Thanks !

Comment: Where are the closing brackets for your `foreach()`? Also, you could do this in one query via `WHERE group_id IN (".implode(",", $_POST['group_id']).")"`

Comment: What is the value of `$member_id[0]`? Does it contain multiple IDs? If so, `implode()` it and use `IN`: `WHERE group_id = $group AND member_id IN (" . implode(',', $member_id[0]) . ")`

Comment: @georgecummins yeah $member_id[0] contains multiple values .

Comment: Please, read up on injection attacks, because your code really is rather vulnerable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove all the members of that group then remove condition for `member_id` from your query

```
$query="DELETE FROM member_group WHERE group_id = $group" ;
```

Or if you want to delete the selected members then from your post you have to extract each member like

```
$member_arr = explode(',',$_POST['member_id']);
foreach ($member_arr as $member) {
    $query="DELETE FROM member_group
            WHERE `member_id` =  $member" ;
}
```

If the `$member_id[0]` contains multiple values as you mentioned in the comment then you can write your query with `IN` like

```
$query="DELETE FROM member_group
            WHERE `member_id` IN (".$member_id[0].") " ;
```

Considering that `$member_id[0]` is in the form `1,2,3,4,5,6` so on.If it is in `array` format then you have to use `IMPLODE` like

```
$query="DELETE FROM member_group
            WHERE `member_id` IN (".implode(',',$member_id[0]).") " ;
```